# Examples of proper, non normal schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, integral-extensions, regular-rings

I'm looking for examples of proper, non-normal schemes over a field $k$, whose global section ring does not coincide with $k$.

Looking in the direction of fiber products of simpler objects is often a "standard" way to construct counter-examples, but in this case most of the properties are stable under base change.

In particular I would be interested in knowing what happens in lower and higher dimensions: is it more likely to find something in dimension 1,2 or higher?

Comment: The question is too vague. Every projective variety is the closure of some affine variety, so that doesn't tell you much. You have a better chance of getting a satisfactory answer if you make the question more precise.

Comment: You are right, thank you. I have modified taking out one property that projective spaces do not satisfy, which is somehow the "exotic" thing I am looking for.

Comment: This is even more bizarre. Assuming $k$ is algebraically closed, any reduced irreducible projective variety has global sections $k$. So, what you want would force the scheme to be not irreducible or worse, non-reduced. Is that what you really want?

Comment: Well, $k$ could actually be not algebraically closed. But thank you for pointing out: by the way, what happens if I *don't* take a projective variety? I mean, not every proper scheme has a closed immersion in $\mathbb P^n$, right? Is it also forced to be reduced or irreducible?

Comment: In such matters, not a great difference. Proper varieties which are not projective already are exceptional and more often than not is converted to study of projective varieties by Chow. Non-algebraically closed is also not a serious issue, since if $X$ is a projective variety over $k$, then the global sections are a finite extension filed of $k$ and you can think of the variety as a variety over this extension. Then, the same applies.